# “I enjoy frequently writing” or “I frequently enjoy writing” or “I enjoy writing frequently”?

Tags: grammaticality, verbs, adverbs, word-order

I have a quick question about grammar within a sentence. I'd also like to know why it is like that if someone could provide an answer.

Which of these are correct?

> - Along with fishing, *I enjoy frequently writing.*
> - Along with fishing, *I frequently enjoy writing.*
> - Along with fishing, *I enjoy writing frequently.*

Comment: Implicit in the answer below: rather than "along with", it's better to use "besides", as "along with" can give the impression that you like to fish and write at the same time.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's not really a question of grammar, but a question of what you mean to communicate. I assume that what you mean is that you enjoy writing and that you frequently write. In your sentence it should be clear that "frequently" (or any adverb that you choose) refers to "writing" and not to "enjoy" or "enjoy writing". Compare the following:

- "I enjoy frequently writing" — it may be interpreted as if what you enjoyed was to "write frequently".
- "I enjoy writing frequently" — same as above.
- "I frequently enjoy writing" — it may be interpreted as if you frequently enjoyed writing (but not always enjoyed writing).

Therefore, it's better if you split your sentence to avoid misinterpretation. I suggest something like:

> Besides fishing, I also enjoy writing. I frequently write.

Comment: +1 for the suggestion to split. There are two completely separate thoughts here: a) you enjoy X, and b) you actually do X quite often. (Just think of all those things that you really enjoy, but haven't done in years.) So, I wouldn't mix the two thoughts too much, though they don't have to be in two separate sentences, either. Something along the lines of "I enjoy X and do it quite often" would be just fine IMHO.

Comment: Actually, "I frequently enjoy writing" *does* imply (to me) that you write often, for (as it seems to me) you can't enjoy writing except when you're actually writing. (You can *say* "I enjoy writing" in a general sense, but if you use the word "frequently", it calls attention to the occasions when you enjoy it, which must be a subset of the times you write.) "I frequently enjoy writing" means that "Frequently, I write and enjoy it", although it leaves open the possibility that even more frequently you write without enjoying it.

Comment: "I frequently write" is more natural than "I'm frequently writing".

Comment: @kiamlaluno: Huh? "Implicates I write often"? "Rebate that"? What language are you speaking?

Comment: @Robusto The language I speak is Italian, or Lombard. As I don't have a speech to text converter, I don't speak when I write a comment.

Answer (score 2):

I hate to disagree with Bruno, but there is really nothing wrong with two of your examples:

> Along with fishing, I enjoy writing frequently.
>
> Along with fishing, I frequently enjoy writing.

The latter sounds more natural.

This is the kind of information one puts in the "Other Interests" section of one's résumé. What it represents is a kind of list, even though it contains but two items.

Items in a list don't have to be related by class: "I found four things in the box: a hammer, an old shirt, two books and a car battery." The only relationship between those items is that they were found in a box together. The only relationship between fishing and writing in your list is that they are things you enjoy doing. By stating your preference for fishing first, the reader assumes it is your primary interest. But the fact that you place it in a dependent clause indicates that you also hold writing in high esteem.

Furthermore, constructing the sentence in this way lets you imply that you do both things frequently without having to explicitly state that. And although to *enjoy* a pursuit means to like doing it, it is also a mild way of simply stating that you do something. If I say "I enjoy an occasional evening out with friends," that may mean I delight in the activity, or it may just mean that I "possess and benefit from" those evenings out. It is a way of saying that these evenings out are something I consider to be properly part of my domain.

In short, the ideas don't have to be split. And I must say I find Bruno's much-heralded suggestion,

> Besides fishing, I also enjoy writing. I frequently write.

to be wordy, repetitious, unnecessary, and may not even mean what you originally intended. Certainly it has a different feel from the more relaxed "Along with fishing, I frequently enjoy writing." Perhaps I am wrong, and that is how you would prefer to say the idea after all. But don't be bullied just because a lot of people up-voted the answer.

Comment: +1 for echoing my sentiments exactly. The version with "...I frequently enjoy writing" places the conceptual emphasis on the enjoyment, while "...I enjoy writing frequently" might be taken to mean that it is the _frequency_ of writing you enjoy, rather than the writing itself.

Comment: "Often' sounds more natura herel IMO.